# Choosing to which email address (within same contact) an email goes to

Tags: lotus-notes

All,

This might sound like a very simple question but I am new to Lotus Notes 8 and nobody around me seems to know an answer to it.

As most people, I keep multiple email addresses per contact (ie.: their work and personal email).  (example: john.doe@company.com  and john.doe@gmail.com;  both these email addresses under "John Doe" contact).

When I go to send an email to "John Doe" Lotus Notes 8 just displays "John Doe" on the "To:" field without informing me as to which of both email addresses is the email going to go to.

Does anyone know how I can show / choose which email address is the email going to be send to?

Thanks in advance
m

Comment: StackOverflow is intented for programming questions.  SuperUser.com is the correct forum for end-user question.

Comment: If you mistakenly asked a question on the wrong network site, feel free to [flag] it and ask a moderator to migrate your question to another site. But please make sure first if your question is really on topic on that site :) Opening duplicate questions on multiple sites is generally frowned upon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rich is correct, this is for programming issues but I found the solution, though I am not sure when they introduced it.

This answer may only be valid in Notes 8.5 or later. I use 8.5.3 UP1.

While you are doing type ahead, the contacts name appears below the send to field. If there are multiple addresses the primary one is displayed and a "twisty" is shown at the right side. Mousing over the name expands the twisty to show and allow selection of alternate emails. Here is a sample (with my spouse's email redacted.:-) )

[image]

Enjoy.

/Newbs

Comment: Apologies guys, I was not sure about whether this question was appropriate for stackoverflow (and I didn't know of superuser.com) My bad.

Newbs, the version I have Lotus Notes 8, does not show by default this drop down as I type. Is there an option in the preferences I should change?

Comment: I have opened this question in SuperUser.com

http://superuser.com/questions/453593/lotus-notes-8-choosing-to-which-email-address-within-same-contact-an-email-go

Comment: Do not worry, The etiquette of these places is at times difficult to understand, but it is a reasonably well self policing community. FWIW: I posted my answer on the other site also...